# In Pine Scripting, can the language read user drawn boxes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

- Is it possible to have pinescript read the boxes I draw using the rectangle function and store them into an array
- If it's not possible is there another way to have the pinescript to read user defined boxes and store them into an array

Answer (score 1):

[image]No, Pine Script cannot read the user drawings.

But there is a way -this script allows user to define a box by dragging two of its corners:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)


XLeft = input.time(0,   'XLeft', inline='L', group='Coordinates', confirm=true)
YLeft = input.price(0,  "YLeft", inline='L', group='Coordinates', confirm=true)
XRight = input.time(0,  'XRight', inline='R', group='Coordinates', confirm=true)
YRight = input.price(0, "YRight", inline='R', group='Coordinates', confirm=true)

var label LblLeft = label.new (XLeft,        YLeft,   xloc = xloc.bar_time, style = label.style_circle, size = size.tiny, color = color.maroon)
var label LblRight = label.new(XRight,       YRight,  xloc = xloc.bar_time, style = label.style_circle, size = size.tiny, color = color.maroon)

var box bx = box.new(XLeft,YLeft,XRight, YRight, xloc = xloc.bar_time, bgcolor = color.rgb(213, 222, 255, 37))
```

Borrowed from this elegant script by Trendoscope (HeWhoMustNotBeNamed): https://www.tradingview.com/script/MgsLckWl-Angled-Volume-Profile-Trendoscope/