# how to read drawn lines by user using pinescript in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator, pine-script-v4, horizontal-line

Has anyone a solution how you can work with the price of a horizontal line object which was drawn manually on the chart?

I tried to get lines from the user but that's not a professional work...

Comment: Using `input.price`. Please see similar questions: [ mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76079591/in-pine-scripting-can-the-language-read-user-drawn-boxes/76080029#76080029)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use the `confirm` argument in [`input.time()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dtime) and [`input.float()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dfloat) for getting the X and Y. If it's a horizontal line then you only need the float one.

> confirm (const bool) If true, the interactive input mode is enabled
> and the selection is done by clicking on the chart when the indicator
> is added to the chart, or by selecting the indicator and moving the
> selection after that. Optional. The default is false.